# How to multiply two vectors with different length

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

Let's say I have two vectors:

```
A = [1 2 3];

B = [1 2];
```

And that I need a function similar to multiplication of `A*B` to produce the following output:

```
[
  1 2 3
  2 4 6
]
```

It seems that things like `A*B`, `A*B'` or `A.*B` are not allowed as the number of elements is not the same.

The only way I managed to do this (I am quite new at MATLAB) is using `ndgrid` to make two matrices with the same number of elements like this:

```
[B1,A1] = ndgrid(B, A);
B1.*A1

ans =
 1     2     3
 2     4     6
```

Would this have good performance if number of elements was large?
Is there a better way to do this in MATLAB?

Actually I am trying to solve the following problem with MATLAB:

```
t = [1 2 3]

y(t) = sigma(i=1;n=2;expression=pi*t*i)
```

Nevertheless, even if there is a better way to solve the actual problem in place, it would be interesting to know the answer to my first question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are talking about an [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product).  If A and B are both row vectors, then you can use:

```
A'*B
```

If they are both column vectors, then you can use

```
A*B'
```

The `*` operator in matlab represents [matrix multiplication](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html).  The most basic rule of matrix multiplication is that the number of columns of the first matrix must match the number of rows of the second.  Let's say that I have two matrices, A and B, with dimensions MxN and UxV respectively. Then I can only perform matrix multiplication under the following conditions:

```
A = rand(M,N);
B = rand(U,V);

A*B    % Only valid if N==U (result is a MxV matrix)
A'*B   % Only valid if M==U (result is a NxV matrix)
A*B'   % Only valid if N==V (result is a MxU matrix)
A'*B'  % Only valid if V==M (result is a UxN matrix)
```

There are four more possible cases, but they are just the transpose of the cases shown. Now, since vectors are just a matrix with only one non-singleton dimension, the same rules apply

```
A = [1 2 3]; % (A is a 1x3 matrix)
B = [1 2];   % (B is a 1x2 matrix)

A*B    % Not valid!
A'*B   % Valid.     (result is a 3x2 matrix)
A*B'   % Not valid!
A'*B'  % Not valid!
```

Again, there are four other possible cases, but the only one that is valid is `B'*A` which is the transpose of `A'*B` and results in a `2x3` matrix.